# Greasemonkey script to replace text in html

Tags: greasemonkey

i want to make Greasemonkey script to replace text in html like this:

`<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" data-gifsrc="http://example.com/image.gif">`

to

`<img src="http://example.com/image.gif">`

in website thechive.com

please help me, thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried something ? could you share what you have done so far to help other guide you in the right direction

Comment: This is pretty easy to achieve in javascript, but you have to at least try something before we can help you.

Comment: sorry, i've tried this `$("body").children().each(function () {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace('data-gifsrc','src') );
});` and it's not working.

Comment: Post an MCVE and link to a target page that actually has that structure. (Default thechive.com pages don't seem to.)

Comment: here is it: [link](http://thechive.com/2015/08/28/animals-can-be-real-dckheads-sometimes-17-gifs/) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot find the `data-gifsrc` attribute on the mentioned website, youi cannot assume the JQuery would be present and available for Greasemonkey.

```
// attribute name
var attrName='data-gifsrc';

// list all images
var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");

// loop every images
for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
  // check for attribute
  if(imgs[i].attributes[attrName]) {
    // set image source
    imgs[i].src=imgs[i].attributes[attrName].value;
    // remove attribute
    imgs[i].attributes.removeNamedItem(attrName);
  }
}
```

Comment: here is a post has data-gifsrc attribute [link](http://thechive.com/2015/08/28/animals-can-be-real-dckheads-sometimes-17-gifs/) i've tried your script but it not working. i don't know why?

Comment: typo `lenght` instead of `length`